# Same Query for same table with different columns (for different versions)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Same Query for different schema?

Hi,

I have a query. It queries a table for some data. However, because there are 2 different versions of the database, so the table columns are changed. for example:

for version #1, table1 has columns: id, value, name
for version #2, table1 has columns: id, value, title

(when it is #2, there is a new table2 in the database. I use to decide whether it is #1 or #2.)

Now, I need to write a query to adapte to both versions in one query.

```
            IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table2', 'U') IS NULL
            BEGIN
                -- version #1
                SELECT *
                FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t1.Name = t3.Name ......
                ...

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- version #2
                SELECT *
                FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t1.title = t3.Name ......
                ...
            END
```

When I run this for version #2, it reports error: t1.Name invalid column name.

I think probably, I can use EXEC to get around this problem. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I tried TRY CATCH, it still reports the same error.

The weird thing I found is: I have another query, it does:

1) create a temp table #Ldap 
2) insert some data into temp table #Ldap using openquery (for active directory).
3) then use the above logic to decide whether it is version #1 or #2.

It works fine although it highlights the t1.Name as error in the management studio's editor. It does not report is as error.

This makes me wondering: does SQL compile the entire query first? or, else?

Anyone knows a solution?

thanks

Comment: . . I assume the temp table version works because you create the temporary table in advance so it has the right columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL will try to parse and evaluate all column references. You can get away with referencing tables that don't exist (deferred name resolution), but you can't get away with columns that don't exist on tables that do. The parser does not care what your `IF` and other conditional logic might yield at runtime. This is why you can't do this, either:

```
IF (1=1)
  CREATE TABLE #foo...
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE #foo...
```

The parser blocks something even that simple, even though the `ELSE` could never possibly run.

Yes, the way around this is dynamic SQL (or a more stable design in the first place).

Comment: @urlreader please [see this, there is a big difference between `EXEC()` and `sp_executesql`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `exec` to get around this.  The issue is occuring during the compilation phase of processing.  It doesn't find the column in the table (thank you Aaron), so it fails.

Unfortunately, you cannot catch compile-time errors using `if` or even `try catch` blocks.

However, you seem to understand the right solution, which is to use dynamic SQL.

You could also fix this by creating a view on `t1` that had the same column name in both versions, and then using that view.

Comment: Anyway +1 for the view idea.

Comment: It is a good idea. However, in my case, I can not use it. In my case, I will have to create view dynamically (because of the way the database designed & security), which still have the same issue. Guess I have to use EXEC to do. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution might be to create a database view on table1, with a field called something like `title_Name` (defined as table1.Name for version #1, and as table1.title for version #2), and use the database view instead of table1 in your query, joined like so:

```
INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t1.title_Name = t3.Name
```