# Stored procedure can't modify and update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to write a stored procedure. The stage table doesn't contain `TransformBusinessID` so I need to be added.

If I execute my query I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'TransformBusinessID'

What am I breaking in the code ?

Here is the code:

```
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns
               WHERE Name = N'TransformBusinessID'
                 AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tst.Store'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE tst.Store 
        ADD TransformBusinessID INT
END;

WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BusinessEntityID DESC) AS INT) AS NewTransformBusinessID
    FROM 
        tst.Store
)
UPDATE CTE
SET TransformBusinessID = NewTransformBusinessID;

END
```

So it looks like the query can't generate this column from the stored procedure, but manually (as a solo query), it works.

Answer (score 2):

[Deferred name resolution](https://littlekendra.com/2021/10/18/deferred-name-resolution-in-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-functions/) allows your procedure to reference *objects* that don't exist yet (it gives you the benefit of the doubt that you'll create them before you execute the procedure), but it doesn't let you reference columns that don't exist yet on objects that do (you don't get the same benefit). I don't have a good reason behind the implementation, but them's the rules (and [it's come up before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622186/61305)).

So, try dynamic SQL, which escapes the evil clutches of the parser:

```
...
    ALTER TABLE tst.Store 
        ADD TransformBusinessID INT
...

EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER 
        (ORDER BY BusinessEntityID DESC) AS INT) 
        AS NewTransformBusinessID
    FROM tst.Store
)
UPDATE CTE
SET TransformBusinessID = NewTransformBusinessID;';
```

Comment: It can probably be renamed to "random name resolution" :)